# SQL subquery and column naming issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, postgresql, subquery

Deal all

1. this is correct code

   ```
   SELECT MAX(inflation_rate) AS max_inf
     FROM (
         SELECT name, continent, inflation_rate
         FROM countries
         INNER JOIN economies
         USING (code)
         WHERE year = 2015) AS subquery
   GROUP BY continent;
   ```
2. this is incorrect code

   ```
   SELECT MAX(subquery.economies.inflation_rate) AS max_inf
   FROM
   (SELECT countries.name, countries.continent, economies.inflation_rate

   FROM countries

   INNER JOIN economies

   ON countries.code = economies.code

   WHERE economies.year = 2015) AS subquery
   GROUP BY subquery.countries.continent;
   ```

Why 2nd one is not allowed ?

Comment: Please tag the question with the DBMS you are using. SQL Server or PostgreSQL?

Comment: Why would you use a subquery here at all? This is just basic aggregation.

Comment: The table names inside a subquery are not visible outside of it. This is by design.

Comment: I apologize if the post contains insufficient information. Next time i will make it correctly and thanks all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    MAX(subquery.economies.inflation_rate) AS max_inf   -- 3
FROM (
    SELECT 
        countries.name,                                 -- 1 
        countries.continent, 
        economies.inflation_rate
    FROM ...) AS subquery                               -- 2
GROUP BY 
    subquery.countries.continent;                       -- 3
```

You are using a subquery (2). This subquery returns three columns: `name`, `continent`, `inflation_rate` (1). Only these names are known outside the subquery, but nothing else. So the superior query does not know anything about where did the column names come from. The table or the table schema is irrelevant.

So for the superior query the only relevant information is: The name of the subquery and the column names (3):

```
SELECT 
    MAX(subquery.inflation_rate) AS max_inf   -- change
FROM (
    SELECT 
        countries.name,                                 
        countries.continent, 
        economies.inflation_rate
    FROM ...) AS subquery                               
GROUP BY 
    subquery.continent;                       -- change
```

Comment: I is so helpful  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write `subquery.countries.continent` as you've a subquery and you renamed it - so `subquery.continent` is enough

```
SELECT MAX(subquery.inflation_rate) AS max_inf FROM 
(SELECT countries.name, countries.continent, economies.inflation_rate
FROM countries INNER JOIN economies
ON countries.code = economies.code

WHERE economies.year = 2015) AS subquery
GROUP BY subquery.continent
```

Comment: Similarly `subquery.inflation_rate`.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am assuming this is postgresql you could simplify this and get rid of the subquery.

```
SELECT continent
    , max(inflation_rate) as max_inf
FROM countries
INNER JOIN economies USING (code)
WHERE year = 2015
group by continent
```

Comment: Would the answer be different for MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh only syntactically because you can't use the **using** shortcut in sql server. And since that was in the "correct" code from the OP I assumed it can't be sql server. But simply changing to the join predicate to ON it would be the same. :P